# php append takes more time using ajax

Tags: ajax

I have a div tag whose id is 'dynamo' in index.php. I appended about.php file (when clicked on 'about' link in index.php) to the div tag using:

```
  $('#abt').click(function () {     
  $.ajax({
        url: "about.php",
        success: function (response) {
            $('#dynamo').html(response);
            document.getElementById('dynamo').scrollIntoView(true);
         }
     });
  });
```

When i test using xampp in localhost it works fine without any delay of appending the about.php and i get the intended results.
But when i upload to  web server and try it, it takes more than a minute to get appended. The whole website comes to standstill till about.php is appended.
Why does it takes so long? How to overcome these? 
Thanks

Comment: What's the size of the about.php file?

Comment: the size of about.php is 6 KB only